# Getting the length of a curved bout

Tags: r, events, time-series

I need the length of the bout from the moment when the temperature is falling till the moment when the temperature is stabilized again and is not decreasing or rising more than 0.1 per time unit.

```
Lines <- "
 time   Temperature
1         38.3
2         38.5
3         38.9
4         38.6
5         38.2
6         38.0
7         37.6
8         37.2
9         37.4
10        37.6
11        37.8
12        38.1
13        38.3
14        38.4
15        38.3
16        38.3
17        38.5
18        38.9
19        38.6
20        38.2
21        38.0
22        38.1
23        38.4
24        38.6
25        38.6
26        38.2
27        38.5
28        38.3
29        38.4
30        38.3
31        38.0
32        38.1
33        38.4
34        38.6
35        38.6
36        38.2
37        38.0
38        37.7
39        37.4
40        38.0
41        38.1
42        38.1
"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

[image]
**Update:**
Furthermore the temperature has to decrease steadily (without increasing between) and in sum more than 1 unit in a bout. And I need all the events in a time-series.

Comment: The definition of a bout is unclear.  Why does your second bout start at time 35 instead of starting at time 18?

Comment: because the temperature should fall more than 1 unit in the whole bout otherwise it should be quited and not counted as those.

Comment: If it started at 18 and ended at 41 it would start with a fall end with a change of <= 0.1 and the bout would contain a drop of more than 1 unit.   Do you meant that it must fall steadily to a value that is at least one unit before? For example, c(38, 37.1, 37.3, 36.2, 36.4, 35.3, 36, 37, 38, 38,1) would _not_ be a bout?

Comment: Yes thats what I want :)